# Grabbing data from join table, and still grab the data if there is no results for join table

Tags: c#, linq

I have a 2 tables, employees and office
I want to return all the employees regardless if they have an office (not having an office is a new requirement).  But if they do have an office I want to return all the office details.

right now the query is only returning employees that have an office... which is not ideal

```
var employeesDetails = from emp in details.FindEmployeeByLastName(lastName)
join office in details.Offices on emp.EmployeeID equals office.EmployeeID
select new {
    EmpID = emp.EmpID
    OfficeID = (office == null) ? -1 : office.OfficeID,
     //...etc
}
```

Edit I know I have to do change this line
 join office in details.Offices on emp.EmployeeID equals office.EmployeeID to a left outer join...

Comment: Does `Employee` have a property `Office`? And what kind of linq is this?

Comment: nope, think I screwed that up... let me edit.. okay its good. Employee has no ties to Office, but Office has ties to Employee (with EmpID) No two employees can share the same office, but some employees can have no office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to accomplish something that, in database terms, is called a "left outer join". To accomplish this in LINQ requires using the `DefaultIfEmpty` method to produce a default object for the missing right-hand side, as described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx)

In your case, it would look like:

```
var employeesDetails = from emp in details.FindEmployeeByLastName(lastName)
                       join office in details.Offices on emp.EmployeeID equals office.EmployeeID into offices
                       from empoffice in offices.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new {
                         EmpID = emp.EmpID
                         OfficeID = (empoffice == null) ? -1 : empoffice .OfficeID,
                         //...etc
                       }
```

Comment: thanks, I knew how to do this in sql, but couldn't translate it to linq! wish they had a converter

Comment: (BTW: fixed the linq query; it was referencing "details" instead of "emp" in the subsequent clauses, which isn't what you want.)

Comment: the second from is throwing error. Type argument for this method cannot be inferred from the usage. worked well when I didn't have select new{ }

Comment: yeah, i misread your question and there is no emp.Offices collection, so the original query was right. my mistake. try this one. If that doesn't work I'll need to see your actual class schema to see what isn't matching up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to circumvent the inner join:

```
var employeesDetails = from emp in details.FindEmployeeByLastName(lastName)
let office = details.Offices
                    .Where(o => emp.EmployeeID == o.EmployeeID)
                    .FirstOrDefault()
select new {
    EmpID = emp.EmpID
    OfficeID = (office == null) ? -1 : office.OfficeID,
     //...etc
}
```